# Filter images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a portfolio page

[image]

I have filter buttons

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="cbp-l-filters-button cbp-l-filters-left">
    <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item">All</div>
    <div data-filter=".personal" class="cbp-filter-item">Personal</div>
    <div data-filter=".professional" class="cbp-filter-item">Professional</div>
    <div data-filter=".freelance" class="cbp-filter-item">Freelance</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My filter buttons does not seems to work, and I'm not sure what went wrong.

---

## jQuery

```
$('.gallery').cubeportfolio({
  filters: '.gallery,.cbp-item',
  loadMore: '#js-loadMore-lightbox-gallery',
  loadMoreAction: 'click',
  layoutMode: 'grid',
  mediaQueries: [{
    width: 1500,
    cols: 5
  }, {
    width: 1100,
    cols: 4
  }, {
    width: 800,
    cols: 3
  }, {
    width: 480,
    cols: 2
  }, {
    width: 320,
    cols: 1
  }],
  defaultFilter: '*',
  animationType: 'rotateSides',
  gapHorizontal: 10,
  gapVertical: 10,
  gridAdjustment: 'responsive',
  caption: 'zoom',
  displayType: 'sequentially',
  displayTypeSpeed: 100,

  // lightbox
  lightboxDelegate: '.cbp-lightbox',
  lightboxGallery: true,
  lightboxTitleSrc: 'data-title',

});
```

---

## HTML

```
<div class="gallery cbp cbp-caption-active cbp-caption-zoom cbp-ready" style="height: 1347px;"><div class="cbp-wrapper-outer"><div class="cbp-wrapper">   

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 img-pop cbp-item personal" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 277px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
   <a href="/assets/img/portfolio/13/1519524545-0-13.png">
     <img class="hvr-shrink" src="/assets/img/portfolio/13/1519524545-0-13.png">
   </a>
 </div></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 img-pop cbp-item professional" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 277px; left: 287px; top: 0px;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
   <a href="/assets/img/portfolio/29/1519600525-0-29.jpg">
     <img class="hvr-shrink" src="/assets/img/portfolio/29/1519600525-0-29.jpg">
   </a>
 </div></div>

</div>
```

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Please include example code for the HTML you are applying that plugin to, in the question itself. When you update your portfolio with working code, this question will be of little to no use to later visitors.

Comment: I added the some of the HTML code of my portfolio now.

Comment: I have removed the live site link from this question. The question as it stands shows the code involved, which is good, but the live site is liable to change over time, and will not be a reliable expression of the problem you had in September 2018. Furthermore, the question is off-topic because there is no specific problem statement (other than "not working", which is rather vague). Are you able to update the post with what the problem was exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters property is supposed to be a css selector to your parent element containing your filter buttons. You currently have `.gallery,.cbp-item` which neither of those are a parent element for the buttons.

To fix just apply the correct selector for a parent element of your buttons like

```
 filters: '.cbp-l-filters-button',
```

The explanation of the various options for the `cubeportfolio()` method should be in the documentation that you received with the package you downloaded

Comment: It works, thanks for your help. I will also review the documentation.

Comment: Dang it Patrick ... you beat me to it, and you knew it would work with a class, where I wasn't sure and was going to advise using an ID. It's so hard to build up your reputation on SO - there's always someone who's just a bit faster/better than me!

Comment: @Josh don't worry about speed, see ["Fastest Gun in the West Problem" post on the meta Stackechange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Be more concerned with the content of your answer: does it answer OP's and possible future users' problem, is it informative, and etc. And as long as your answer is good people will upvote even if someone else has the accepted answer (I have quite a few like this). So I would suggest actually undeleting yours and letting it stand or update it if you wish with your newfound knowledge

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you for your advice - I have undeleted and added an update to the post. Some of the responses to that post are fascinating - a much hotter topic than I ever imagined! I'll just keep trying to provide the best answers I can in the clearest language I can with the objective of helping people out and hope I can maybe pick up some points along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Since cube portfolio is a paid plugin, the documentation isn't exactly freely available online, but [I found some docs](http://www.video-brochure.co.uk/assets/plugins/cubeportfolio-jquery-plugin/documentation/#filters)* and I think I know whats up. Give this a go.

First I think you need to add an ID to the div that contains the filter links

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="cbp-l-filters-button cbp-l-filters-left" id="filter-container">
    <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item">All</div>
    <div data-filter=".personal" class="cbp-filter-item">Personal</div>
    <div data-filter=".professional" class="cbp-filter-item">Professional</div>
    <div data-filter=".freelance" class="cbp-filter-item">Freelance</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the jQuery, the `filters` property value should be set to `filters: '#filter-container',`.

Try that and let me know if it fixes your issue.

**Update:** as has rightfully been pointed out by Patrick, there is actually no need to add an ID, simply changing the filters property value to one of the classes on that container `div` such as `cbp-l-filters-button` will do the job.

---

*it appears someone else bought the cube portfolio plugin and just uploaded the whole directory to their server without removing documentation

Comment: If you found some docs actually explaining the filter property you should link that. I myself couldn't find any helpful documentation on that front and had to dig into the code itself to find this information :)

Comment: You're clearly more advanced in javascript than I am - I started off by looking in the code, but soon realised it was going to take me a little while to wrap my head around it, so thought I'd try hunting down some documentation first. As the small print says in my post - it doesn't look like those docs are supposed to be available, but rather simply been uploaded by someone who didn't know better (or wasn't being paid enough).